# How to deserialize the data using JSONAPI-Serializer module of NodeJs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, serialization

I am working with nodejs and using module named "[JSONAPI-Serializer"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonapi-serializer) for serialization and deserialization purpose.

I am able to serialize the objects without any issue but not able to deserialize the same serialized data.

So,using below code I am able to serialize the data:

**root@test$: node test.js**

```js
var data = [{ id: 1},{ id: 2 }];
var JSONAPISerializer = require('jsonapi-serializer').Serializer;

var UserSerializer = new JSONAPISerializer('id', {"test":"me"});
var users = UserSerializer.serialize(data);
console.log("Serialized:\n", UserSerializer.serialize(data));
```

Below is the generated result for the same:-

```js
Serialized:
 { data: [ { type: 'ids', id: '1' }, { type: 'ids', id: '2' } ] }
```

But on deserialization, I am not able to make it work trying to perform the same example as documented in document of "JSONAPI-Serializer".

Can anyone tell me the way to deserialize the above data using "JSONAPI-Serilizer"  ?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing your deserialization code. Here is mine that works.
The issue what missing "attributes" option for serializer.

```
var data = [{ id: 1},{ id: 2 }];
var JSONAPISerializer = require('jsonapi-serializer').Serializer;
var JSONAPIDeserializer = require('jsonapi-serializer').Deserializer;

var UserSerializer = new JSONAPISerializer('id', {attributes: ['id']});
var users = UserSerializer.serialize(data);

console.log(users)
var UserDeserialize = new JSONAPIDeserializer();
UserDeserialize.deserialize(users)
.then(a => console.log(a))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the information and its really appreciated. I am very new to nodejs and school student. I am trying to learn these things :)

Comment: No worries. Just mark the answer as solution please :)

Comment: Hi wookieb, I have one query again. here you have serialized the data with attribute but what if we need to serialize without using any attribute here: var UserSerializer = new JSONAPISerializer('id', {attributes: ['id']});